# How do I create a unicode edit control that will accept characters with codes above 127

Tags: c, winapi

How do you create a unicode utf8 edit control  drag/drop from toolbox,  that will accept characters with codes above 127?

```
//Always return length size 1 for any unicode character
u_int length = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. However this may help you: "To obtain the exact length of the text, use the WM_GETTEXT, LB_GETTEXT, or CB_GETLBTEXT messages, or the GetWindowText function." via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Please provide us a bit more information: What are you trying? What do you have? What is the test case? ...

Comment: `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` returns the lenght in *characters*, any unicode character is 1 character.

Comment: I'm trying input a unicode utf-8 encoding character for example: `Black heart suit` of bytes `0xE2 0x99 0xA5 (e299a5)` but how do i have edit control display it and allocate buffer?

Comment: This makes no sense. You need to spend more time phrasing your question.

Comment: Guys, to clarify his question. I believe he is talking about creating a text-box that will accept characters with codes above 127 without mangling them or converting them to some code page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are writing this in Visual Studio as a C project, and you have a dialog with a child edit called IDC_TEXT, and hwnd is your dialog handle:

```
// Declarations
long lRet = 0;
wchar_t *wszText = NULL;

// Retrieve the length of the edit text
lRet = SendDlgItemMessageW(hwnd, IDC_TEXT, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);

// Assign memory based on retrieved length
wszText = (wchar_t *)malloc(((lRet + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)));

// Check that memory allocation succeeded
if (wszText != NULL)
{
    // Retrive the text from edit
    lRet = SendDlgItemMessageW(hwnd, IDC_TEXT, WM_GETTEXT, (long)(lRet+1), (long)wszText);

    // Check that text is not NULL
    if (wszText == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Failed to retrieve text!", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxW(hwnd, wszText, L"Edit Contents", MB_OK);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Failed to assign memory!", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
```

Note that the code uses SendDlgItemMessageW and that your dialog box must be created with DialogBoxW. If you are using an older Visual Studio, you must select Unicode build so the program gets built using the wide APIs.

Not sure why you say you want to create a UTF8 edit box in your post. Windows uses UTF16 to represent characters natively, so it can only create a UTF16 edit box. If you need to convert between UTF8 and UTF16 or vice versa, take a look at the MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte APIs.

Edit: Corrected UTF16/UCS2 issue per David's comment below.

Comment: UCS2 and UTF-16 are not the same. Windows uses UTF-16 mostly (UCS2 for the console).

Comment: If you are using a tab control, make sure to create the tab dialogs using CreateDialogW.